# Wildcard Virtual Hosts Ubuntu

Tags: linux, apache, ubuntu, vhosts, virtual-hosts

I'm looking to setup wildcard virtual hosts in Ubuntu. I've set it up on a WAMP setup pretty easily, but I don't know enough about Linux to know how the setup differs.

The goal is to be able to create folders like:

```
site.weblocal
site2.weblocal
site3.weblocal
etc.....
```

without having to add individual vhosts each time. Someone has recommended dnsmasq?

Any tips would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: "Someone has recommended dnsmasq" And have you looked into dnsmasq? Is there a reason it's not sufficient?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

for Ubuntu it goes as simple as

```
sudo apt-get install dnsmasq
sudo echo "address=/weblocal/127.0.0.1" >> /etc/dnsmasq.d/weblocal
sudo /etc/init.d/dnsmasq restart
```

Answer (score 3):

sudo apt-get install dnsmasq

sudo gedit /etc/dnsmasq.conf

add this line "address=/.weblocal/127.0.0.1"

then restart dnsmasq using following

sudo service dnsmasq restart