# How to use wildcard with dnsmasq in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ubuntu, dns, wildcard, dnsmasq

04
I am trying to config wildcard in the host file

```
127.0.0.1 *.example.com
```

so i installed dnsmasq
I have tried

```
echo address=/example/127.0.0.1/ | sudo tee -a /etc/NetworkManager/dnsmasq.d/local
echo address=/.example/127.0.0.1/ | sudo tee -a /etc/NetworkManager/dnsmasq.d/local
sudo /etc/init.d/dnsmasq restart
sudo service network-manager restart
```

followed answers of:

[Wildcard Virtual Hosts Ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10873439/wildcard-virtual-hosts-ubuntu)

But nothing has worked so far.

Comment: Please have a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70057218/520637

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some unknown reason even after restarting network-manager and dnsmasq the problem was not solved. But after restarting my PC it was working fine.

Answer (score 0):

what you can do is

```
sudo echo 'address=/example.com/127.0.0.1'  >> /etc/dnsmasq.conf
```

is equivalent to

```
*.example.com
```

or

```
*.*.*.example.com
```

and restart the dnsmasq service

```
sudo /etc/init.d/dnsmasq restart
```

I think this will do the trick.

Comment: I did it but the problem still persisted for some unknown reason. After restarting my pc it was working for reason