# wildcard for local dev hosts

Tags: hosts, wildcard-subdomain, dnsmasq

I am switching between multiple projects recently. All running locally on the same IP but with different domains... actually it's always `*.local` (like `foo.local`, `bar.local` and so on). I could continue adding those to my `/etc/hosts` file but it's not very clean way.

That's why I thought of setting up `dnsmasq.conf` so I've ran (obviously as root):

```
echo "address=/local/172.17.0.1" >> /etc/dnsmasq.conf
service dnsmasq restart
```

Unfortunately it doesn't work. I mean when I run `foo.local` (exists in `/etc/hosts`) it's ok but `foo2.local` (not in hosts) it doesn't. What do I miss?

Answer (score 0):

`address=/local/172.17.0.1` in `dnsmasq.conf` should resolve the subdomain `*.local` too.

Have you tried the following?

```
address=/.local/172.17.0.1
address=/#.local/172.17.0.1
address=/#local/172.17.0.1
```

Make sure that `dnsmasq` is restarted.

Answer (score 0):

I have a simple config for local domain `.loc`, please (1) do place it in your `/etc/dnsmasq.d/`, (2) modify domain names to your needs and (3) restart *dnsmasq*:

```
###################
# .loc DNS domain #
###################

auth-server=loc            # auth server for .loc
host-record=loc,127.0.1.1  # glue A record
#auth-zone=loc,127.0.1.0/24 # zone spec (with subnet -- wildcards not working)
auth-zone=loc/24           # zone spec (no subnet -- wildcards working)
address=/.loc/127.0.1.2    # wildcard record (*.loc => 127.0.1.2)
mx-host=loc                # MX record

####################################
# custom .loc DNS domain A records #
####################################

host-record=what.ever.loc,127.0.1.100
```

This config allows to mix wildcards and custom records (`host-records`) as required.